# C# ListView Remove Items

Tags: c#

I would like remove item just before because its shows me twice the same item when I click on, but here, item number -1 doesn't exists
And I don't know why.
How I can resolve this ?
Thank you.

```
private void DEXTarget_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logs("DEX(TMAPI) Target Checked");
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(-1);
            PS3.ChangeAPI(SelectAPI.TargetManager);
            Var.API = true;
        }

        private void CEXTarget_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Logs("CEX(CCAPI) Target Checked");
            PS3.ChangeAPI(SelectAPI.ControlConsole);
            Var.API = false;
        }
```

Log:

```
private void Logs(string text)
        {
            Var.lst = this.listView1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm"));
            Var.lst.SubItems.Add(text);
        }
```

Comment: RemoveAt uses 0 based index.

Comment: no because my first item is : Logs("Opening Program");

Comment: The first item is index 0, the second item is index 1.  So RemoveAt(-1) isn't going to work, the index position -1 doesn't exist.

Comment: So? Items still count from 0 upward. -1 is an indicator for 'Item not found'.

Comment: `ListViewItemCollection.RemoveAt` will through `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if index is less than 0.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` Items Index start from `0` and ends with `Count-1`.

I think you are looking for removing the last Item from the `ListView`

Try This:

```
listView1.Items.RemoveAt(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```